# echo a specific meta_key queried through a custom post

Tags: wp-query, customization, post-meta

I'm new to coding but love tinkering around (on Virtual Server) with bits to upgrade my current website when I have the time.

What would be really useful to me would be to post an individual attribute of a custom post but most of the support seems to be for showing the whole post.

I have a table of members in an area of my site only available to admin and I would like to post a publish date of their subscription **(custom post type 'subscription')** in the table.

I already have the **$UserID** - which should match up to the **meta_key 'member'** in the Custom Post...

How do I go about echo-ing a publish date in the table when the **meta_key 'member' = the userID?**

I can post the necessary code I have so far if anyone thinks it helpful... I've been tearing my hair out over this for the last few days as all the code I've tried posts inaccurate dates - either the date of the page or a seemingly random spread that doesn't seem to have any relevance to the individual users.

The table is in a foreach construction.

EDIT: Added Code. 
GETING THE USERS FIRST PUBLISHED SUBSCRIPTION?? 
Is the annotated bit I'm having trouble with. I can explain any of the functions if you like too

```
<?php if (current_user_can('manage_options')) { ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="twelve columns">
  <div class="boxed">
    <h2>Event Administration for event <?php echo get_the_ID(); ?></h2>
    <?php
      $tickets = getTicketsForEvent(get_the_ID()); //EventID through ai1ec-plugin
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>User (Full Name)</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Subscription</br>Expiry/Renewal</th>
            <th>Subscriber</br> Since</th>
            <th>Photo</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
<tbody>
          <?php foreach($tickets as $ticket) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $ticket['name']; ?>
<br/>(
                <?php $useremail = $ticket['email'];
                    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $useremail );
                    $IDuser = $user->ID;
                    echo bp_get_profile_field_data( array( 'field'=>'Full (Legal) Name - Not Displayed*','user_id'=>$IDuser));
//this is to get the required field out of BuddyPress profile information filled out
                    ?>)
                </td>
              <td><?php echo $ticket['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?php $useremail = $ticket['email'];
                    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $useremail );
                    $IDuser = $user->ID;
                    $telno = bp_get_profile_field_data( array( 'field'=>'Mobile phone number - Not Displayed*','user_id'=>$IDuser));
//this is to get the required field out of BuddyPress profile information filled out
                    {?><a href="tel:<?php echo $telno;?>"><?php echo $telno; }?></a>
                </td>
                <td><?php $useremail = $ticket['email'];
                    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $useremail );
                    $IDuser = $user->ID;
                    echo getSubscriberType($IDuser);
                    $subscriptions = getUserSubscriptions($IDuser);?></br> <?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($subscriptions[0]['expiry'])); ?>
                </td>
// this bit uses some code in function.php just to display the type of subscription. (can also post if required)
<!-- //GETING THE USERS FIRST PUBLISHED SUBSCRIPTION?? \/  \/  \/  \/  \/  -->
<td>
<?php
$useremail = $ticket['email'];
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $useremail );
$IDuser = $user->ID;
global $wpdb;

$post_ids = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->subscriptions WHERE member ='$IDuser'" );

foreach($post_ids as $id){

    $postdate = get_the_date("Y-m-d",$id );
    echo $postdate;
?>
</td>

<!-- //GETING THE USERS FIRST PUBLISHED SUBSCRIPTION?? /\  /\  /\  /\   -->
                <td><?php $useremail = $ticket['email'];
                    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $useremail );
                    $IDuser = $user->ID;
                    echo get_avatar( $IDuser, 60); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
          <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Apologies if it's a bit of a mess - I'm no more than an amateur coder....

Comment: Yes, please add your code.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are doing. Is "`meta_key 'member' = the userID`" something in postmeta? Or usermeta? Or a custom table? Exactly which date are you looking for? A post publication date?

Comment: Yes in each custom post the meta key 'member' is the wordpress userID who it's assigned to (ie ticket custom post or subscription custom post). What I want to do is find the publication date of the subscription CP using its meta tag 'member' from the ticket CP.... What's the method - I can only find blogs & tutorials about using a key to show or call whole posts... Where I want to use a meta_key value to call a post and find it's publication date...

Comment: So would go $ticket > get email > email to find userID > find custom post (type 'subscription') that meta_key 'member' = $userID > show publish date of that custom post....

Comment: Right I think I know a way round it... Is there an easy way of just displaying the first post date of a specific UserID... As the subscriptions post themselves with the author being the userID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so was way simpler than I thought in the end and didn't involve a lot, just was approaching it in completely the wrong way:

The same can be achieved like this:

```
     /*GETING THE USERS FIRST PUBLISHED SUBSCRIPTION?? */
$useremail = $ticket['email'];
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $useremail );
$IDuser = $user->ID;
$args = array(
              'posts_per_page' => 1,
              'post_type' => 'subscription',
              'author' => $IDuser,
              'meta_key' => 'state',
              'meta_value' => 'complete',
              'orderby' => 'date',
              'order' => 'ASC',
              );
$first_post = new WP_Query($args);
//    '<pre>'.print_r($first_post).'</pre>'; // You can use this to check what the query produces to make sure you're on the right track.
if ($first_post->have_posts()) {
    $first_post->the_post();

    the_time('M j, Y');

    wp_reset_postdata();
```

That should give you the first published subscription belonging to `$IDuser` but can be used for any type of post if you change the `'post_type'`